# Allowed topics?

Tags: discussion

I am new to this site and I am a bit confused about allowed topics. You say in the about page that you should not ask 'primary opinion-based' questions. Are you not allowed to ask value and policy questions, or what do you mean by 'opinion-based'?

Comment: Policy questions would likely more properly belong on the Politics site -- though maybe I'm missing the point there. Note that the 'primarily opinion-based' language isn't restricting any particular *topic*; on my reading it's just saying that you shouldn't ask the question in a way which would demand a mostly-opinion answer.

Comment: [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) might be constructive to review here too.

Comment: I decided years ago to never use 'opinion' when reasoning since I realized it is mainly used as a way to shot down an argument without giving good reasons for it. Because all answers are in the end just your opinion: if we talk about facts your way to add the bayesian logic will be based on your unique experience so in the end just be your opinion. if we talk about definitions a similar situation occur but even more so are you allowed to say that you like defining it like x rather than y. With policies I mean 'what should we do' type of questions which are a kind of value about actions.

Comment: Values are must obviously opinion based since it is very hard to find objective or universal values. So what are we allowed to talk about in this forum. To me philosophy is the love of wisdom. The best definition I ever heard on wisdom is Durant's in 'the history of philosophy' where he say that wisdom is 'the coordination of desires in the light of all experience'. According to this definition philosophy is all about how to coordinate desires, which science is not allowed to talk about, but it seems like you are cutting out this line of questioning by not allowing opinion?

Comment: To be clear: the language about avoiding asking for "**mostly**-opinion" answers is a global SE guideline. To my mind it is fundamentally about avoiding polls and other undesirable question-types. It has nothing to do with topicality and doesn't indicate any particular subject as "off-topic". It's about the way we frame concerns, in order to optimize for "good" subjective expertise (I really would recommend reading the linked article above.) At any rate, it's not anyone here imposing limitations on what you can ask about.

Comment: Briefly: feel free ask about *any* specific problems you're encountering in your study of philosophy, regardless of topic. But do try to avoid polling; SE works best when we focus on practical and meaningfully *answerable* concerns.

Comment: Ok, I think I get the goal of the rule (I guess I will found out soon enough if I don't :) ). Thanks for the answer.